# Bar chart doesnt show up on Excel VBA users form

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone help me please? Thank you!!!!!

I have a Excel user form for supervisors to assign tasks. it has a bar chart on it to show how many items assigned to team member. the goal is to help the supervisor see how many items he assigns to each person. It works perfectly fine on my computer, but if I share it on a shared drive, my coworkers can open and use it, but the bar chart won't show. it should look like the picture.

[image]

the code is

```
Private Sub Assign_Invoice_cmb_AssignTo_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim RowNumber As Integer
Dim AssignChart As String

    For i = 0 To Assign_Invoice_lb_Invoice.ListCount - 1
        If Assign_Invoice_lb_Invoice.Selected(i) Then
           Assign_Invoice_lb_Invoice.List(i, 7) = Assign_Invoice_cmb_AssignTo.Value
           RowNumber = i + 15
           Assign_Invoice_lb_Invoice.Selected(i) = False
        End If
    Next i
    
    Call AssignInformation(Sheet2.Range("CD12").Value, Assign_Invoice_lb_Invoice, Sheet2.Range("CD9").Value, Assign_Invoice_lbl_Assigned, Assign_Invoice_lbl_NotAssigned)
    Call EmbedChart("AssignChart", Assign_Invoice_img_AssignQty)
   
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub EmbedChart(ChartName As String, MyImage As MSForms.Image)

Dim Cname As Chart
Dim Fname As String

Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
Set Cname = Sheet2.ChartObjects(ChartName).Chart

Sheet2.ChartObjects(ChartName).Activate
Cname.Export Filename:=Fname, filtername:="GIF"
MyImage.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to an access issue.  If the user opening it doesn't have read/write access on the shared drive, the program would not be able to save the chart image and/or wouldn't be able to display it.

Comment: Thank you Ben! that's very helpful!